# Speed up Multidimensional numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, computational-complexity

I have the following 9-D integral, where the domain of integration is a nine-dimensional hypercube of unit length. The problem is that Mathematica takes too long to evaluate this. Is there any specific way to speed it up using parallelization or using a specific integration strategy?

```
  u1 = 1; u2 = 10^(12); u3 = 
         10^(-12); u4 = 1; u5 = 1; u6 = 100; u7 = 0.01; u8 = 10000; u9 = 
         10^(-8);

    α = 0.3; β1 = 0.25; β2 = 0.4; β3 = 0.54; \
    γ1 = 0.6; γ2 = 0.7;

w1 = u3; w2 = u3 u5; w3 = u3 u5 u7; w4 = u9; w5 = u2 u3 u9; w6 = 
 u2 u3 u4 u5 u9; w7 = u8 u9; w8 = u1 u2 u3 u8 u9; w9 = u6 u8 u9; 

num = 1/(2 π I)^9 (w1)^z1 (w2)^z2 (w3)^z3 (w4)^z4 (w5)^z5 (w6)^
   z6 (w7)^z7 (w8)^z8 (w9)^
   z9 Gamma[-z1] Gamma[-z2] Gamma[-z3] Gamma[-z4] Gamma[-z5] \
Gamma[-z6] Gamma[-z7] Gamma[-z8] Gamma[-z9] Gamma[α + z1 + z2 +
      z3 + z4 + z5 + z6 + z7 + z8 + z9] Gamma[β1 + z1 + z5 + 
     z8 + z9] Gamma[β2 + z2 + z6 + z7 + z8] Gamma[β3 + 
     z3 + z4 + z5 + z6] Gamma[
    1 - γ2 - z4 - z5 - z6 - z7 - z8 - z9] Gamma[
    1 - γ1 - z1 - z2 - z3 - z5 - z6 - z8];

limit = 1;

num1 = num /. {z1 -> -0.04 - limit I + 2 I z1, 
     z2 -> -0.02 - limit I + 2 I z2, z3 -> -0.01 - limit I + 2 I z3, 
     z4 -> -0.005 - limit I + 2 I z4, 
     z5 -> -0.0025 - limit I + 2 I z5, 
     z6 -> -0.00125 - limit I + 2 I z6, 
     z7 -> -0.000625 - limit I + 2 I z7, 
     z8 -> -0.0103125 - limit I + 2 I z8, 
     z9 -> -0.0101563 - limit I + 2 I z9} // Simplify;

(2 I)^9 NIntegrate[
   num1, {z1, 0, limit}, {z2, 0, limit}, {z3, 0, limit}, {z4, 0, 
    limit}, {z5, 0, limit}, {z6, 0, limit}, {z7, 0, limit}, {z8, 0, 
    limit}, {z9, 0, limit}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: I answered a question concerning a 8D integral today where Monte-Carlo methods made it faster - they tend to perform well in these high-dimensional cases: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225250/72682 Use `Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^6}`

Comment: Thanks. Although the speed improves but the error estimate is greater than the actual value.

Comment: In a well-behaved integral the error is proportional to $1/\sqrt{n}$, where $n$ is the number of sample points.  That's assuming the sampling is dense enough to detect significant features.

Comment: Alright. But I got an error of  23.8086 when I used "MaxPoints"-> 10^6.